# Jquery event.preventDefault() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want my menu to show and hide list items on click by default they are hide. The problem is my menu is generated in admin section so it auto assigns url of website to it if i set URL field of particular link to null in menu options. so when i click it reloads home page.

What i want is that when i click any parent li it should stop generating default event so used prevent default. but in my case it is not working and it reloads the page after showing list items of there parent.

Here is a fiddle
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h1b3eb4p/)

Html

```
<div class="mega-col col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4" data-type="menu">
    <div class="mega-col-inner">
        <ul>
            <li class="parent dropdown-submenu mega-group"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href=""><span class="menu-title">Massachusetts Stores</span><b class="caret"></b></a>
                <div class="dropdown-mega level2">
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-inner">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 mega-col" data-colwidth="12" data-type="menu">
                                <div class="mega-col-inner">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class=" "><a href="index.php?route=common/location_details&amp;loc_id=24"><span class="menu-title">Burlington Mall, MA</span></a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class=" "><a href="index.php?route=common/location_details&amp;loc_id=25"><span class="menu-title">Burlington Mall, MA - Cart</span></a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="parent dropdown-submenu mega-group"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href=""><span class="menu-title">New Jersey Stores</span><b class="caret"></b></a>
                <div class="dropdown-mega level2">
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-inner">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 mega-col" data-colwidth="12" data-type="menu">
                                <div class="mega-col-inner">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class=" "><a href="index.php?route=common/location_details&amp;loc_id=26"><span class="menu-title">Brunswick Square Mall, NJ</span></a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class=" "><a href="index.php?route=common/location_details&amp;loc_id=30"><span class="menu-title">Garden State Plaza, NJ</span></a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class=" "><a href="index.php?route=common/location_details&amp;loc_id=27"><span class="menu-title">Menlo Park Mall, NJ</span></a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class=" "><a href="index.php?route=common/location_details&amp;loc_id=29"><span class="menu-title">Ocean County Mall, NJ</span></a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class=" "><a href=""><span class="menu-title">Rockaway Townsquare, NJ</span></a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="parent dropdown-submenu mega-group"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href=""><span class="menu-title">New York Stores</span><b class="caret"></b></a>
                <div class="dropdown-mega level2">
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-inner">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 mega-col" data-colwidth="12" data-type="menu">
                                <div class="mega-col-inner">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class=" "><a href="index.php?route=common/location_details&amp;loc_id=31"><span class="menu-title">Galleria at White Plains, NY</span></a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class=" "><a href="index.php?route=common/location_details&amp;loc_id=42"><span class="menu-title">Manhattan, NY-Toys 'R' Us </span></a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="parent dropdown-submenu mega-group"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href=""><span class="menu-title">North Carolina Stores</span><b class="caret"></b></a>
                <div class="dropdown-mega level2">
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-inner">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 mega-col" data-colwidth="12" data-type="menu">
                                <div class="mega-col-inner">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class=" "><a href="index.php?route=common/location_details&amp;loc_id=32"><span class="menu-title">CrabTree Valley, NC</span></a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class=" "><a href="index.php?route=common/location_details&amp;loc_id=2"><span class="menu-title">Fayetteville, NC</span></a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
  $("#li_menu169 li.parent.dropdown-submenu.mega-group").click(function(event) {
    var id = $(this).prop('id');
    if (id == 'yes') {

        //i want to prevent
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).children('.dropdown-mega.level2').show();
        $(this).children('.dropdown-mega.level2').hide();
        //redirect
    }
});

Css

li.parent.dropdown-submenu.mega-group .dropdown-mega.level2 {
display: none;
}
li
 {
padding:10px;
position: relative;
margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: At first sight I would say you would like to `prevent default` on the `<a>` element, instead of `<li>`.

Comment: You can move your `event.preventDefault()` outside of `if/else`

Comment: @Rolice but than how willi show and hide my list children on click actualy i show them or hide them when particular parent LI is clicked. You can view my fiddle

Comment: @jai i tried but stil it reloads. u can see my fiddle

Comment: `id` is an attribute not a property, and in any case - nothing has an id of "yes"?!?

Comment: @Jamiec every time this if condition will be false so i wrote my code in else that was my logic.. i dont see any other logic coming in my mind

Comment: please add something to your anchors href's. using href=" " seems to be the issue. Use "href="#"" instead

Comment: you've made some mistakes. Look into my answer and the JSBIN: https://jsbin.com/gigowopijo/3/edit?html,js,console,output there it is "correcT" and working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hk1w89zw/

Not sure what you were trying to acheive with the `id prop`. In general it's better to set the `onClick` event on a link (`<a>`-tag) instead of the `li`. and use following jQuery code:

```
$("li.parent.dropdown-submenu.mega-group > a").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.dropdown-mega.level2').hide();
    $(this).closest('.parent').find('.dropdown-mega.level2').show();
});
```

Comment: if we click on a menu, and then click on it again, it expands again..however, it should be contracted and closed

Comment: Thanks alot.. Its exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want something like this

```
$("#li_menu169 li.parent.dropdown-submenu.mega-group").click(function(event) {
    var id = $(this).prop('id');
    if (id == 'yes') {

        //i want to prevent
    } else {

        $(this).children('.dropdown-mega.level2').show();
        $(this).children('.dropdown-mega.level2').hide();
        //redirect
        window.location.href="location_of_the_filehere";
    }
    event.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: it sounds odd.. since i try editing your code in jsfiddle. does it shows error in the dev tools?

Comment: no errors it just reloads it. it doesnt show me child elements of this LI on mouse click

Comment: do you have local files for that and try it localy??i believe that should do the work you need

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit that I got your code wrong.

Here is a https://jsbin.com/gigowopijo/3/edit?html,js,console,output (JSBin).

First you don't have a list with the id "#li_menu169". Add it to the ul element

```
<div class="mega-col col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4" data-type="menu"><div class="mega-col-inner">
    <ul id="li_menu169">
```

Later on you're showing and hiding the same elements which is a bit confusing. Therefore I would recommend hiding all inner elements first and than showing the inner elements of "this" stuff.

```
 $("#li_menu169 li.parent.dropdown-submenu.mega-group").click(function(event) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    if (id === 'yes' && typeof id !== undefined) {
        console.log("I'm there");
        //i want to prevent
    } else {
        console.log("i'm here");
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.dropdown-mega.level2').hide();
        $(this).find('.dropdown-mega.level2').show();
        //redirect
    }
});
```

Within the JSbin it is working as you expect.

Comment: i tried the way you said but it didnt solve any thing for me.. it keeps on reloading

Comment: Can u please update the Fiddle because the way u are saying isnt helping me

Answer (score 0):

Catch the `event` when its trigger out

```
$("#li_menu169 li.parent.dropdown-submenu.mega-group").click(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

}
```

Comment: Didnt get you please refer to my fiddle accordingly